# mongodb do not write record to disk ,why?

Tags: linux, mongodb

i start a new mongodb instance and local connect use mongo shell,add a user with userAdminAnyDatabase role,but when i exit the shell,start another shell,i can not find
the record of db.system.user which i insert the first time,why?

```
# mongo --port 27017
> db.getSiblingDB('admin')
admin
>  db.addUser({user:"sa",pwd:"sa",roles:["userAdminAnyDatabase"]})
{
        "user" : "sa",
        "pwd" : "75692b1d11c072c6c79332e248c4f699",
        "roles" : [
                "userAdminAnyDatabase"
        ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("519ddd610b4ea57201ceb000")
}
> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519ddd610b4ea57201ceb000"), "user" : "sa", "pwd" : "75692b1d11c072c6c79332e248c4f699", "roles" : [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] }
> exit
bye

# mongo --port 27017
> db.system.users.find()
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.system.users.find()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security feature as of MongoDB 2.4.x. You don't want other users to be able to see the hashed passwords.

A user would need to have the `userAdmin` role and be logged in to view the collection.